# Upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 aborted without showing any error message

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I am trying to upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 by using the following command but the process aborted without showing any error message.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

[image: Term output]

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to do: `sudo do-release-upgrade` i also have same error. It seems to be an error due to the command. I suggest you to install 18.04 from bootable usb drive.